# Validate one form field or another form field based on a form selection, but not both at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do you validate only check when PAYMENT_TYPE check is selected and also validate only creditcard when PAYMENT_TYPE creditcard is selected?

```
   class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :check, :creditcard
    PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card" ]
    validates :creditcard, :presence => { :if => :creditcard? }
    validates :check, :presence => { :if => :check? }

     def creditcard?
     check == nil
     end

     def creditcard?
     creditcard == nil
     end
   end
```

form

```
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
```

...

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :pay_type %><br />
      <%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES,
      prompt: 'Select a payment method' %>
    </div>
    <div id="creditcard">
      <%= f.label :creditcard, class: "creditcard" %><br />
      <%=  f.text_field :creditcard, class: "creditcard" %>
    </div>
    <div id="check">
      <%= f.label :check, class: "check" %><br />
      <%=  f.text_field :check, class: "check" %>
    </div>
```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below. Your checking should be on `pay_type`.

```
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :check, :creditcard, :pay_type
    PAYMENT_TYPES = [ "Check", "Credit card" ]
    validates :creditcard, :presence => true, :if => :creditcard_selected?
    validates :check, :presence => true, :if => :check_selected?

     def check_selected?
        pay_type == "CHECK"
     end

     def creditcard_selected?
        pay_type == "Credit Card"
     end
  end
```